# OGR Python API FlatGeobuf edits are not persisted

Tags: python, ogr, flatgeobuf

I'm using GDAL 3.5.1 OGR's Python bindings (on MacOS) to create features within a FlatGeobuf file but my changes are not being persisted.

Relevant Code:

```
data_path = "/Users/user/data/trails.fgb"
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("FlatGeobuf")
datasource = driver.Open(data_path, 1)
layer = datasource.GetLayerByIndex(0)

def setup_function():
    for key, value in test_features.items():
        feature = ogr.Feature(layer.GetLayerDefn())
        feature.SetField("name", key)
        shape = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(value)
        feature.SetGeometry(shape)
        layer.CreateFeature(feature)

    assert len(test_features.values()) > 0, "no test features"
    assert layer.GetFeatureCount() == len(test_features.values()), "test setup problem creating features"
```

Both `assert`s pass so I know that I am successfully creating features. However when the `Datasource` and `Layer` objects go out of scope, or the script exits, no data is persisted. I have tried forcing a data write with `datasource.SyncToDisk()` but this fails with

```
RuntimeError: Error while creating /Users/user/data/trails.fgb_ogr_tmp.fgb
```

Permissions on the `/Users/user/data` directory are `777` and I can successfully execute the same workflow using GeoPackage, so this problem seems unique to FlatGeobuf.

Comment: What happens if you write to a new file?

Comment: @IanTurton what happens is that it raises an error telling me the geometry is the wrong type! The GeoPackage driver is more lenient, as it permits LINESTRING WKT for a layer with MULTILINESTRING geometry type, but FlatGeobuf does not. Thanks for your input, addressing the geometry type issue fixed my problem. If you want to add a response I will mark it as the answer

Comment: You can self answer

Comment: The GeoPackage driver should not be lenient. If the layer has been created as LINESTRING it should deny MULTILINESTRING. If the layer has been created as generic GEOMETRY then inserts will work. Verify the behavior and consider to create a GDAL issue into GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately this issue was caused by an attempt to insert geometry with the wrong type (LINESTRING instead of MULTILINESTRING) into the FlatGeobuf layer. This only became apparent - with a meaningful error message - when attempting to create a new layer with the same geometries.